# KeyPress or KeyDown event not getting buind with html element

Tags: jquery, html

when we are pressing any key event not getting fired.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myP" contentEditable="true">
        This is a paragraph. you can edit me, i am editable.
        <span contenteditable="false" class="go" id="go">
            <strong >This is strong thing</strong>
        </span> after strong
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

//script part

```
$("#go").keydown(function() {
  debugger;
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```

when we set contentEditable = true then we can edit content of that element in my case I am having span inside div and i want to delete that span on backspace key press. but it is getting navigate me to previous page. Means it is redirecting me to previous page according to history.

Comment: If you could create a fiddle that shows the bug that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ee81bf1x/1/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should take into consideration that .keydown is fired if you press a key while inside an input.

```
<input contenteditable="false" class="go" id="go">
```

You could listen for all events if you attach your handler on the *body* instead of the span:

```
$("body").keydown(function() {
  debugger;
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```